# InstallShield installer that can check to see if a component is installed and not reinstall it

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am working on installshield projects for a group of applications. (After this release switching to WiX)

There are 2 "components" that all the different applications need to be able to run. Is there a way to add these components to each individual installer and have them check and not re install these components are will I have to make a a separate installer for these two programs and tell the customers to install these first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Shared Components".  Done correctly, MSI will properly reference count the component and not uninstall it until the last product comes off.   Whether it'll be reinstalled or not depends on the file version of the key file.  A newer product could have a newer version of the shared component and a reinstall would be correct.  If an older product had an older version it would not reinstall as this would be incorrect.